# Separate the solutions of `integrate.quad`

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm now trying to obtain the apropriate solution for the integral with the array upper limit. Everything works fine, However, function contain two solutions, I need to get rid of the second one. Here is the code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from typing import List

def integrand(z,alpha,beta,gamma):
    return (2**(-0.5 + 1/(2.*(1/(1 + z))**(3*gamma)))*3**(-0.5 + 3/(2.*(1/(1 + z))**(3*gamma)))*23**(1/(1 + z))**(-3*gamma)*np.exp(1 - (1/(1 + z))**(-3*gamma) - alpha/(2.*beta) + alpha/(2.*(1/(1 + z))**(3*gamma)*beta)))**(-1)


def multi_integrate(alpha,beta,gamma,lb:float, ub_ls:List[float]) -> List:
    results = []
    # loop through all upper bounds
    for ub in ub_ls:
        results.append(quad(integrand,lb,ub,args=(alpha,beta,gamma)))
    return results

lb = 0
ub_ls =z

def Hz_th(alpha,beta,gamma,z):
    return multi_integrate(alpha,beta,gamma, lb,ub_ls)
```

For arbitrary array `z` and some values of the free parameters alpha, beta, gamma we have that there are two solutions, first one is the correct one. However, it is not that easy to separate the array, since it has slightly unusual for me form:

```
[(0.00014626812936348427, 1.6239024498819118e-18),
 (0.000150015526635659, 1.6655069172217707e-18),
 (0.00015073611990008352, 1.6735071095573097e-18),
 (0.00015635608256829605, 1.7359012290751435e-18),
 (0.0001746488221728651, 1.938991435999794e-18)...
```

Maybe someone could help?

Comment: The second number isn't a solution.  It's an error estimate.

Comment: Okay... How could I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you know how to index - a list, tuple, or array?

Answer (score 0):

The exact thing you are looking for is an [underscore.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) It is the proper way
to ignore or disregard the return values which you don't need.

Let's say you have a function like this.

```python
def func(z,alpha,beta,gamma):
    # Do something
    return z,alpha,beta,gamma
```

So below is the *beautiful syntax* you can sprinkle on your code:-

```python
z = [1,2,3]
a = 1
b = [1,2]
g = 5.3

z,_,b,_ = func(z,a,b,g)
print('z = ',z)
print('b = ',b)
```

Output:
z =  [1, 2, 3]
b =  [1, 2]

```python
z,_,_,g = func(z,a,b,g)
print('z = ',z)
print('g = ',g)
```

Output:
z =  [1, 2, 3]
g =  5.3

```python
z,*parameters = func(z,a,b,g)
print('z = ',z)
print('parameters = ',parameters)
print(parameters[0])
print(parameters[1])
print(parameters[2])
```

Output:
z =  [1, 2, 3]
parameters =  [1, [1, 2], 5.3]
1
[1, 2]
5.3